# Recover a Lebesgue-integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu(\cdot)$ be a probability measure on $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Consider a measurable but not integrable function $F: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

(2) Prove that there exists a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that:

(2a) $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi$ continuous and strictly increasing, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \phi(x) = +\infty$;

(2b) $$ \int_X \phi( F(x) ) \ \mu(dx) \ < \ +\infty $$

EDIT:

(1) Find an example in which there is no function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$

($f(0)=0$, $f$ continuous and strictly increasing, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = +\infty$) such that:

$$ \int_X f(x) F(x) \ \mu(dx) \ < \ +\infty $$

Comment: (1) is doubtful since $f$ cannot exist if the integral of $F$ on $X\cap[x,+\infty)$ is infinite for every $x$.

Comment: Please provide a counterexample then. For instance, if $\mu(dx) = dx$, function $F(x) =x^{-1}$ is not integrable over $[y,\infty)$ for every $y$. However $f(x) = x^{-1}$ makes the product $f(x) F(x)$ integrable.

Comment: Neither the Lebesgue measure on the halfline as a *probability measure* nor the function $f:x\mapsto1/x$ as an *increasing and going to infinity* function (see (1a)) are the first examples I would suggest... Anyway, as I said, **any** $F$ and $\mu$ satisfying the condition I wrote would do, but you could try $F(x)=\mathrm e^x$ and $\mu(dx)=dx/F(x)$ on $x\gt0$.

Comment: Ok, my example was wrong. In your example, can you formalize that there are no $f$s making the product not integrable?

Comment: The answer has been edited

Comment: view $F(x)$ as a random variable, define $\phi$ in terms of its distribution fctn.

Comment: To mike: can you be more precise please? What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Yes: let $f$ denote any nonnegative increasing function, then there exists $c\gt0$ and $x$ such that $f\geqslant c$ on $[x,+\infty)$. Hence the integral of $fF$ on $[0,+\infty)$ is at least $c$ times the integral of $F$ on $[x,+\infty)$, which diverges.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let's focus on the main question now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making bounded an unbounded integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127275/making-bounded-an-unbounded-integral)

Comment: If what you call *the main question* is part (2), then this is a duplicate.